# Craft 3 RC 11: Deleting Assets Issue

Tags: assets, craft3

When I delete an asset in the CP, the asset/file will be deleted, but it is still shown in the assets list (without thumb).

The issue can't be solved with the "Update asset index" function. (There is also the file listed: "Missing file"!)

> yii\base\ErrorException: unlink(/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxxxxxxx/storage/runtime/assets/sources/108.png): No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxxxxxxx/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/helpers/BaseFileHelper.php:407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to have been fixed a few hours ago:

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2463

You could apply the fix yourself for an immediate solution:

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/commit/30db5af5b596e267db136a218209a65cc9fde36e

Answer (score 1):

Problem is related to the issue Luke pointed out but in a different location within the file.

Change line 1060 in file /craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/AssetTransforms.php

from

```
if (!FileHelper::unlink($file)) {
    Craft::warning("Unable to delete the file \"{$file}\".", __METHOD__);
}
```

to

```
if (file_exists($file) && !FileHelper::unlink($file)) {
    Craft::warning("Unable to delete the file \"{$file}\".", __METHOD__);
}
```